# invoking a method with handler every time a Fragment is visible to user and l remove its callback is that fragment is not visible

Tags: java, android

I want a run a handler only when a particular Fragment is visible to user when that fragment is not visible, I want handler to be stopped. My problem is handler is running when I have another Fragment on top. My Code is (Code in Fragment):

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  updatedNotification();
}

private void updatedNotification() {
  String alertInterval= TextUtils.isEmpty(prefManager.getKeyAlertTimeInterval())?"15":prefManager.getKeyAlertTimeInterval();
  long timeInMillis = Long.parseLong(alertInterval)*1000;
  runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updatedNotification();
        }
    };

  handler=  new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(runnable,timeInMillis);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try overriding the [`setUserVisibleHint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) or [`setMenuVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setMenuVisibility(boolean)) and add the handler code in it:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

  if (isVisibleToUser) {
     updatedNotification();
  } else {
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
  }
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean menuVisible) {
  super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);

  if (menuVisible) {
     updatedNotification();
  } else {       
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
  }
}
```